# Email clients are putting single space characters in HTML emails

Tags: outlook, character, html-email, whitespace, apple-mail

I am sending HTML emails using the PHP mail function and have found that email clients are inserting single space characters at regular intervals.  This is inconvenient when part of the email is a url.

I devised a test script to illustrate this:

```
<?php

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$message .= '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456<br>';
$headers = 'From: sender@domain.com' . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$subject = 'Inserting spaces into HTML';
mail('receiver@domain.com', $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

In Outlook and Apple Mail, but not MailHog, this is the result:

> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
> 78901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456

Note where the above has wrapped where the space occurred.

I have tried this with more lines and found that if you count the characters in the tags and the spaces themselves, this occurs every 998 characters (I think).

The simple workaround is to pad the preceding HTML with formatting so that the space does not occur within the url.

Does anyone have any explanation?

Comment: Not sure this is related but your text is outside of your HTML!

Comment: Not sure how that happened, but as the answer below explains, it's not really an html issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321) defines that lines in an email must be at most 1000 bytes (including the final CRLF (\r and \n):

> The maximum total length of a text line including the `<CRLF>` is 1000 octets

Since line breaks in HTML are just white space anyway, I'd just keep my lines under the maximum.

If you really need longer lines, you can use quoted-printable encoding and add a `=` as a soft line break at the end of the line (as per rule 5 in section 5.1 of [RFC 1341](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1341)). Note that quoted printable only allows 76 bytes per line.

> Rule  #5  (Soft  Line  Breaks):  The   Quoted-Printable
> encoding REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
> characters long. If longer lines are to be encoded with
> the  Quoted-Printable encoding, 'soft' line breaks must
> be used. An equal sign  as  the  last  character  on  a
> encoded  line indicates such a non-significant ('soft')
> line break in the encoded text.

So this

```
one=
line
```

would be rendered as

```
one line
```

Comment: Assuming that a `<br>` tag ends a line, the lines above are only 100 charcters including the tag.  In an HTML email what does RFC 5321 count as a line?

Comment: A `<br>` does *not* end a line. SMTP does not know (or care) about HTML. A line is everything up to the next CRLF. The message you build is one long line.

Comment: Thank you.  I corrected the test script by adding `. "\r\n"` after `<br>` which, of course, removed the "random" spaces.